# JAVAで、 utf8 以外のテキストファイルを読み込むと文字化けする

Tags: java

JAVAで、テキストファイルを読み込む処理を下記の様に作ったのですが、
読み込むテキストファイルが、EUCやShift-JIS、GB2312などのように、
UTF-8以外の場合、読み込んだStringの中が、文字化け状態です。

ユニコード（UTF-8)に変換して、読み込まれていないのが原因？

尚、読み込むファイルの文字コードの判定方法は不明なので、
今は、下記の様に固定で、UTF-8を指定しています。

★事前に文字コードを判定する処理や、このソースへ追加／修正することで、
  JAVAが何かの変換処理で？サポートしている？文字コードなら、
  UTF-8として、Stringに、読み込めるようにできないでしょうか？

```
InputStreamReader   fr  = null;
BufferedReader      br  = null;

try {
    fr  = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(strFile_name), "UTF-8");
    br  = new BufferedReader(fr);

    // 既存のreadLine()では\rまたは\n、および\r\nにて改行とみなしている。
    String strLine  = null;
    int    iCount   = 0;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) { // null=ファイルの最後
        file_text_line.add(strLine);
        iCount++;
    }

    br.close();
    fr.close();

    return iCount;  // 読込み成功（注意：0件の時もある）
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
```

Answer (score 7):

昔の知識ですが、EUC-JPやShift_JIS系なら `"JISAutoDetect"` を指定する手があります。

Java8の時代にはもうないかも、と思ったけど[まだある](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)みたいです。

Answer (score 5):

まず基本的にStringの内部表現はUTF-16固定です（JVMのオプションで変えれなくもない）。`InputStreamReader`の二つ目の引数はReaderで読み取ろうとしているバイト列のエンコーディングを指定するためで、ご質問の場合はテキストファイルのエンコーディングを指定する必要があります。
残念ながらJava標準ライブラリには与えられたバイト列から自動でエンコーディングを判定してStringにしてくれる関数などはありませんので、手動できめるか、自分で判定用関数を書くか、何らかの外部ライブラリを使うしかありません。
以下いくつかJava用ライブラリの例ですが、まず前提として何の追加情報もないバイト列からエンコーディングを100%当てる方法はないので（ウェブブラウザとかでも良く文字化けしますよね）外れた場合の対処手段は用意したほうが良いと思います。

- [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/)（つい最近までGoogle Chromeで使われてたやつ）
- [juniversalchardet](https://code.google.com/archive/p/juniversalchardet/)（昔のFirefoxのアルゴリズムをJavaに移行したもの）
- [jChardet](http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/)（同上）

正直精度はどれも微妙ですが、ICU4Jの例を以下に。

```
//ファイルのバイトストリーム（一応バッファーに通す）
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(strFile_name));

//ICU4JのCharsetDetectorクラスでエンコーディングを推測できる
CharsetDetector cd = new CharsetDetector();
cd.setText(bis);
CharsetMatch cm = cd.detect();

//cm.getConfidence()であってる確率を取得（0-100）
//この値で判定を採用するかを決めるのもありだと思います
//与えたバイト数が短いと基本低確率
if(cm.getConfidence() > 70) {
    //７割以上の確立であってる
} else {
    //７割以下であってる
}

//判定されたcharsetを取得
String charset = cm.getName();
//または直接Readerを取得
Reader r = cm.getReader();
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。バイナリ読込みでStringへ読み込む処理もありますので、そちらの方が、ライン読み？で勝手に文字コード変換されたり？していないので、よいかもしれないですね。とりあえず、上記ソースコードを埋め込んで、判定処理してみます。

Comment: 結果、UTF16(BE)のファイルを、IBM420_ltrと判定してしまいます。やはり、判定制度は、微妙なんですね。

Comment: 「バイナリ読込みでStringへ読み込む処理」が何のことなのかわかりませんが、「ライン読み込み」でしたら正しいエンコーディングが指定されたReaderがあれば`BufferedReader`に通せば`getLine()`で1行ずつ取得できます。　あとIBM420_ltrと判定された時の`getConfidence()`はどのくらいでしたか？

Comment: 現実的な解として、「Mule」や「Meadow」といった多言語対応の(入力ファイルや出力ファイルのエンコードを変更する機能を持つ)エディタでファイルを開いてみて、エンコードを判断するのが良いのではないでしょうか。エンコードを確実に判断できるプログラムは存在しないのですから、人の目で判断する。そのツールとしては多言語対応エディタが適しているという事です。